# Android Desktop environment name?

Tags: android, linux

I have been reading about Linux. I found linux itself is just a kernel . The many Linux based distros like Ubuntu, mint etc, use desktop environemnts like GNOME .As android use linux based kernal. What is the desktop environment name. Or Android have its own method to display?

Comment: Android is an Operating System and not a Desktop Manager

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but **may** be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com (and you're more likely to get a good answer there). Please review [the guidelines for posting in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android uses its own "Desktop-Environment" or rather Window manager. Interesting sidenote: There are few OS that aim to bring GNOME to phones (e.g. on the pine phone).

Samsung for example calls its User Interface "One UI" and used to call it "TouchWiz". For stock Android, I have never heard a name for it. But it's not based on anything like GNOME or KDE as they really suck too much to serve billions of people (GNOME e.g. lagging like nuts)